# Get Client Active Directory UserName from Django

Tags: python, django, http, active-directory, request

I have to design an intranet app. We control users access by using Windows Active Directory. 
The user can post some data then the app must persist user post data and Windows AD username in the database.

Is there a way to get AD username (client not server) from Django?

Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can do it only if client browser is Internet Explorer using "Integrated Windows Authentication" http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication (turn on it in IE, credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/680838/3033586) ... in Django docs I've found only one reference to this problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/