# Django : How to get client computer user name in view.py

Tags: python, django

> Server Setup  - Linux-CentOS7, Apache2.4, MySQL, Python3.6.8, Django2.2
>
> -
>
> Client OS - Windows10, Windows7, CentOS, MacOS ...
>
> Client Computer Hostname = MyPC_011
>
> Client Computer logged in username = user-A

In views.py I want to use client machine logged in username(user-A) when user access django website page.

This is my view.py

```
def home_view(request):
    # Get IP address of client computer
    client_ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    # Get Host Name of client computer
    client_host = request.META.get('REMOTE_HOST')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I get IP address by REMOTE_ADDR,  REMOTE_HOST is empty, USER and USERNAME display server username.

> 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'REMOTE_HOST': '', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'WSGIServer/0.2', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'PATH_INFO': '/', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.5.107', '

How to get client machine logged in username when user access django website page?

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680804/is-it-possible-for-a-django-application-to-know-users-windows-domain-name/680838#680838

Comment: Any one tried this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/auth-remote-user/